# how to sort text file alphabetically with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file that contains English words translated into Arabic that I want to arrange alphabetically,

text file :

```
entrenched = ترسخ

hypotenuse =وتر

conquered = التغلب

tempted = يغري

intentional = متعمد
```

ps: some words contains more the one like this :

```
indistinguishable = لا يمكن تمييزه 
spot the subtle = بقعة الخفية
```

I want to check just the first char of every lines and make the sort , I tried but it didn't work :

```
def sorting(filename):
infile = open(filename,encoding="utf8")
words = [] 
 for line in infile:
 temp = line.split()
  for i in temp:
  words.append(i)
 infile.close()
 words.sort()
 outfile = open("result.txt", "w",encoding="utf8")
 for i in words:
outfile.writelines(i)
outfile.writelines("\n")
 outfile.close()
 sorting("words.txt")
```

Comment: `for i in sorted(words):`

Answer (score 0):

Had to figure out your code indenting :-(

Your code was splitting each line and adding all the words to `words` - I thought you wanted to sort by the first word of each line, so my code below sorts the lines using the `key=` method of `str.sort()` using a function `getfirstword` to work out the first word of the line. Often you'd use a lambda function for this but it's much easier to debug a non-lambda function.

I put the strings into a variable and split the variable, just so it's a [mre] in one file.

```
datatext = """entrenched = ترسخ
hypotenuse =وتر
conquered = التغلب
tempted = يغري
intentional = متعمد
"""

def getfirstword(s):
    '''
    given a string, split off the first word
    '''
    words = s.split(maxsplit=1)
    if len(words)>0:
        return words[0]
    return ""

# takes a complete text - splits it into lines
def sorting(text):
    lines = text.splitlines()
    sortedlines = sorted(lines,key=getfirstword)
    for line in sortedlines:
        print( line )

# could use:
# datatext = open( "words.csv").read()    
sorting(datatext)
```

Result:

```
conquered = التغلب
entrenched = ترسخ
hypotenuse =وتر
intentional = متعمد
tempted = يغري
```